# What's the significance of a wreath hung on the traverse / ridge pole of a tent in a military camp?

Tags: military, france, 18th-century, symbols, tradition

*The first time I saw it, I thought it was odd, but then, 18th century artists love putting strange details in things, so I went on my merry way.  But I've seen it a few times since, and now I've got to know:*

**What's with the wreaths hung on the ridge poles?**

I've seen it multiple times in period artwork depicting french military encampments of the ancien regime (i.e. pre Revolution).  Always an "A" frame style tent, where a canvas is draped over a horizontal pole and the ends pulled outwards and held tight, by staking or tying, to make a triangular sheltered area beneath, always with the horizontal beam extending beyond the canvas at the more accessible end of the tent, and a circle of some sort of what appears to be greenery hooked on the protruding part, like one would put a key ring on a hook.

It's popped up in paintings, engravings, often as a background small detail, and occasionally as a very prominent one, such as in [this piece](https://www.sothebys.com/en/buy/auction/2020/the-rafael-valls-sale-online/jan-peeter-verdussen-a-military-encampment) that went up for sale at Sotheby's depicting a mid-18th century French military camp:

[image: A painting of an 18th century military camp. Men on horses are in front of a tent constructed of canvas draped over a horizontal pole; on the pole there is a wooden sign and a wreath of greenery.]

I've seen just the wooden signs, by themselves, like this one from a [collection of 17th century French military](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/btv1b104651534/f28.item.zoom) images held at the BNF:
[image: A black and white line drawing of a military camp scene. Supplies are being unloaded from an open top wagon to a tent made of a canvas draped over a frame of sticks. Hung from the top pole of the tent is a small sign.]

But I've also seen the wreath by itself, on a tent that didn't appear to be special in any manner, like this engraving of 1756 infanteries by Louis David from [Tome 6 of the BNF collection](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/btv1b10465152p/f74.item.zoom):
[image: An 18th century French soldier stands facing the viewer, attaching a bayonet to his musket. In the background a tent is seen in profile.]

A wreath accompanied by a flag or sign, from [Troupes du Roi 1757 held at Musée de l'Armée](https://www.photo.rmn.fr/archive/06-531398-2C6NU0P3J19G.html):

[image: A scene of an 18th century french military camp depicting soldiers socializing]

Wreath, [soldiers playing card games](https://www.photo.rmn.fr/archive/07-532552-2C6NU0JXPGEQ.html), from a series by Nicolaus Hauffmann of french troops that took park in the AWI:
[image: Three soldiers dressed in white uniforms play cards at a table in front of a white tent]

From the same series by Hoffman, [soldiers eating outside a tent](https://www.photo.rmn.fr/archive/07-532539-2C6NU0JX36Q2.html) with a flag (but no wreath) hung from the ridge pole:
[image: three 18th century soldiers in white uniforms with blue trim use a barrel for a table for their meal and drink]

Same series, same artist, [flag with illegible writing and a small sprig of greenery](https://www.photo.rmn.fr/archive/07-532554-2C6NU0JXPB5U.html), one soldier pouring a drink for another.
[image: an 18th century french soldier in a white uniform pours a drink for another under a tent which is marked with a blue flag]

**Does this have any significance?  Is it some sort of social/cultural custom, or is it perhaps an identifier to signal what the purpose of that specific tent?**

Comment: images with only a wreath [here](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Sutlers#/media/File:Peter_von_Hess_(3)Sutler_Scene.JPG) and [here](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Sutlers#/media/File:Wouwerman_In_Front_of_the_Tent.jpg). Both said to depict [sutlers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sutler)

Comment: "Sutler" seems to be akin to what is known as a "vivandière" in the french army of the ancien régime, and would be a reasonable label for the depictions in the photos in the question. 
 The images @Jan linked depict Dutch and Polish troops, meaning this might be a continental European practice.

Comment: I know that "in the past", a wreath on a building would indicate a tavern/inn. Maybe those tents had the same purpose? That would fit with your illustrations of soldiers drinking and playing cards.